# gathering a large dataframe back into master in dask distributed

Tags: dataframe, dask, dask-distributed

I have a large (~180K row) dataframe for which

```
df.compute()
```

hangs when running dask with the distributed scheduler in local mode on an 
AWS m5.12xlarge (98 cores).
All the worker remain nearly idle
However

```
df.head(df.shape[0].compute(), -1)
```

completes quickly, with good utilization of the available core.

Logically the above should be equivalent. What causes the difference?
Is there some parameter I should pass to `compute` in the first version to speed it up?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `.compute()` you are asking for the entire result in your local process as a pandas dataframe.  If that result is large then it might not fit.  Do you need the entire result locally?  If not then perhaps you wanted `.persist()` instead?

Comment: I do want the whole dataframe collected. Although large it easily fits on. on my machine. The second snippet
  `df.head(df.shape[0].compute(), -1)`
does what I need quite quicikly. I am really asking why does`compute` stall?

Comment: No clue.   That depends on everything in your computation.  It could be anything really.

Comment: ok, but why would `df.head(df.shape[0].compute(), -1)` not have the same problem as `compute()`? Don't they do the same thing?